# How can I get dynamic view from a dynamic lens

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Use `R.view` dinamicly ...

```js
const robotsNames = [ 'da Vinci Surgical System',  'KITT', 'The Tachikomas', 'Toyota violin-playing robot',
    'GERTY', 'Mega Man', 'Rock ‘Em Sock ‘Em Robots', 'Doraemon', 'Awesom-O', 'HK-47', 'ED-209', 'Beer-Fetching Robot',
    'Bishop', 'The Energizer Bunny', 'Clank', 'Daft Punk', 'Johnny 5', 'The Robot', 'Roboto', 'Marvin the Paranoid Android',
    'Lego Mindstorms NXT', 'Robbie', 'Astro Boy', 'The Iron Giant', 'Optimus Prime', 'Roomba', 'DJ Roomba', 'Cindi Mayweather',
    'Rosie', 'Crow T. Robot/Tom Servo', 'K-9', 'The Terminator', 'The Maschinenmensch, aka Maria', 'ASIMO', 'GLaDOS', 'HAL 9000',
    'The Final Five', 'Sojourner', 'Data', 'R2D2', 'Bender Bending Rodriguez', 'Wall-E' ];

const getRandomInt =  R.curry((min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
})
const getRandomFromZero = getRandomInt(0);
const lensRandomRobot = R.pipe(R.length, getRandomFromZero, R.lensIndex);

// NOT WORK...
const randomRobot = R.pipe(lensRandomRobot, R.view);
const robot = randomRobot(robotsNames);

// THIS WORKS ..
// const robot = R.view(lensRandomRobot(robotsNames))(robotsNames) // I dont want to pass the values twiice

console.log(robot);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `R.converge` instead of `R.pipe` in `randomRobot` if you want to avoid repeating `robotsNames`

```js
const robotsNames = [ 'da Vinci Surgical System',  'KITT', 'The Tachikomas', 'Toyota violin-playing robot',
    'GERTY', 'Mega Man', 'Rock ‘Em Sock ‘Em Robots', 'Doraemon', 'Awesom-O', 'HK-47', 'ED-209', 'Beer-Fetching Robot',
    'Bishop', 'The Energizer Bunny', 'Clank', 'Daft Punk', 'Johnny 5', 'The Robot', 'Roboto', 'Marvin the Paranoid Android',
    'Lego Mindstorms NXT', 'Robbie', 'Astro Boy', 'The Iron Giant', 'Optimus Prime', 'Roomba', 'DJ Roomba', 'Cindi Mayweather',
    'Rosie', 'Crow T. Robot/Tom Servo', 'K-9', 'The Terminator', 'The Maschinenmensch, aka Maria', 'ASIMO', 'GLaDOS', 'HAL 9000',
    'The Final Five', 'Sojourner', 'Data', 'R2D2', 'Bender Bending Rodriguez', 'Wall-E' ];

const getRandomInt =  R.curry((min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
})
const getRandomFromZero = getRandomInt(0);
const lensRandomRobot = R.pipe(R.length, getRandomFromZero, R.lensIndex);

// CHANGE MADE HERE
const randomRobot = R.converge(R.view, [lensRandomRobot, R.identity]);
const robot = randomRobot(robotsNames);


console.log(robot);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- The answer from Damon is fine.  [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/?converge) does the job as expected.  But there are several alternatives to consider.  `converge` is very Ramda-specific.  Something better known to the FP world might interest you.  [`lift`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/?lift) is more common.  You can use it like this:

  ```
  const randomRobot = R.lift(R.view)(lensRandomRobot, R.identity);
  ```

  Or, perhaps best would be [`ap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/?ap), which would be perfect except that the parameter order in [`view`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/?view) is opposite what `ap` supplies, so there needs to be a [`flip`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/?flip) as well<sup>*</sup>:

  ```
  const randomRobot = R.ap(R.flip(R.view), lensRandomRobot);
  ```

  You can see these approaches on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20robotsNames%20%3D%20%5B%20%27da%20Vinci%20Surgical%20System%27%2C%20%20%27KITT%27%2C%20%27The%20Tachikomas%27%2C%20%27Toyota%20violin-playing%20robot%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%27GERTY%27%2C%20%27Mega%20Man%27%2C%20%27Rock%20%E2%80%98Em%20Sock%20%E2%80%98Em%20Robots%27%2C%20%27Doraemon%27%2C%20%27Awesom-O%27%2C%20%27HK-47%27%2C%20%27ED-209%27%2C%20%27Beer-Fetching%20Robot%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%27Bishop%27%2C%20%27The%20Energizer%20Bunny%27%2C%20%27Clank%27%2C%20%27Daft%20Punk%27%2C%20%27Johnny%205%27%2C%20%27The%20Robot%27%2C%20%27Roboto%27%2C%20%27Marvin%20the%20Paranoid%20Android%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%27Lego%20Mindstorms%20NXT%27%2C%20%27Robbie%27%2C%20%27Astro%20Boy%27%2C%20%27The%20Iron%20Giant%27%2C%20%27Optimus%20Prime%27%2C%20%27Roomba%27%2C%20%27DJ%20Roomba%27%2C%20%27Cindi%20Mayweather%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%27Rosie%27%2C%20%27Crow%20T.%20Robot%2FTom%20Servo%27%2C%20%27K-9%27%2C%20%27The%20Terminator%27%2C%20%27The%20Maschinenmensch%2C%20aka%20Maria%27%2C%20%27ASIMO%27%2C%20%27GLaDOS%27%2C%20%27HAL%209000%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%27The%20Final%20Five%27%2C%20%27Sojourner%27%2C%20%27Data%27%2C%20%27R2D2%27%2C%20%27Bender%20Bending%20Rodriguez%27%2C%20%27Wall-E%27%20%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getRandomInt%20%3D%20%20R.curry%28%28min%2C%20max%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Math.floor%28Math.random%28%29%20%2A%20%28max%20-%20min%20%2B%201%29%29%20%2B%20min%3B%0A%7D%29%0Aconst%20getRandomFromZero%20%3D%20getRandomInt%280%29%3B%0Aconst%20lensRandomRobot%20%3D%20R.pipe%28R.length%2C%20getRandomFromZero%2C%20R.lensIndex%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20const%20randomRobot%20%3D%20R.converge%28R.view%2C%20%5BlensRandomRobot%2C%20R.identity%5D%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20const%20randomRobot%20%3D%20R.lift%28R.view%29%28lensRandomRobot%2C%20R.identity%29%3B%0Aconst%20randomRobot%20%3D%20R.ap%28R.flip%28R.view%29%2C%20lensRandomRobot%29%3B%0A%0ArandomRobot%28robotsNames%29%3B)**.
- Secondly, bringing in a random source is a strange idea in functional code.  Obviously anything using a random value is no longer referentially transparent.  This is the reason that Ramda does not supply random/shuffle functions.

  Ramda did experiment with randomness at one point, trying to use a referentially transparent version.  But eventually it was given up as a poor match, but [that code](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/commit/56005258) might help you create testable versions of your random-based code.

---

<sup>*</sup>The point is that when `ap` is applied to functions, it behaves like this:

```
ap(f, g)(x); //=> f(x)(g(x))
```

and for functions curried the way Ramda's are, this is equivalent to

```
ap(f, g)(x); //=> f(x, g(x))
```